# Can't apply pattern by key in KeyedStream with Flink CEP

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm trying to emmit an alert for each 2 occurences of events with same ID. To do this, I'm using `keyBy()` to apply my operations according to the ID.

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.{TimeCharacteristic, scala}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.{DataStream, KeyedStream}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time

class Pipeline {

    //{...}

    var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)

    //{...}

    var stream : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/input").name("Stream original")

    var tupleStream = stream.map(new S2TMapFunction())
    var newTupleStream : DataStream[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)] = tupleStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner())
    newTupleStream = newTupleStream.process(new RemoveLateDataProcessFunction).keyBy(new TupleKeySelector())

    Pattern.begin[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]("teste").where(new EventoTesteConditionFunction(2)).times(1)

    val patternStream = CEP.pattern(newTupleStream,pattern)

    val result = patternStream.process(new EventoTestePatternProcessFunction())

    result.writeAsText("/home/luca/Desktop/output",FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)

    env.execute()

}
```

Here is my `TupleKeySelector`:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector

class TupleKeySelector() extends KeySelector[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int),Int]{

    override def getKey(value: (String, Double, Double, String, Int, Int)): Int = {

        value._6

    }
}
```

Here's my `PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner`:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark

class PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner extends AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]{

    var counter : Int = 0
    var eventsUntilNextWatermark : Int = 0
    var lastTimestamp : Long = _

    override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: (String, Double, Double, String, Int, Int), extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {

        if(counter == eventsUntilNextWatermark){

            counter = 0

            var time = new Timestamp(lastTimestamp)
            println("Watermark: ",time.toString)
            new Watermark(lastTimestamp)

        }else{

            null

        }

    }

    override def extractTimestamp(element: (String,Double, Double,String,Int,Int), previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {


        val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        val date = formatter.parse(element._4)
        val timestampAtual = new Timestamp(date.getTime).getTime
        lastTimestamp = Math.max(lastTimestamp,timestampAtual)

        //counter = counter + 1

        timestampAtual

    }
}
```

Here is my `EventoTesteConditionFunction`:

```
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.conditions.IterativeCondition

class EventoTesteConditionFunction(var counter : Int) extends IterativeCondition[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)] {

    private var c  : Int = 0

    override def filter(value: (String, Double, Double, String, Int, Int), ctx: IterativeCondition.Context[(String, Double, Double, String, Int, Int)]): Boolean = {

        if(c == counter-1){

            println("Event: "+value._6.toString)

            c = 0

            true

        }else{

            c = c + 1

            false

        }

    }
}
```

According to the semantics adopted by Flink, I should achieve my goal by using `times(1)` quantifier with my pattern, or even ommitting it. Nevertheless, that's not what I obtained in my output. Here's my test case:

```
//Input events:

(name,timestamp,id) 
(a,2013-02-08 00:14:00,1)
(b,2013-02-08 00:15:00,1) // Event should be emitted here
(c,2013-02-08 00:15:10,1)
(d,2013-02-08 00:17:15,1) // Event should be emitted here
(e,2013-02-08 00:18:20,1)
(f,2013-02-08 00:19:30,0)
(g,2013-02-08 00:20:35.507,2)
(h,2013-02-08 00:21:39.906,2) // Event should be emitted here
(i,2013-02-08 00:22:03.499,2)
(j,2013-02-08 00:23:23.818,2) // Event should be emitted here
(k,2013-02-08 00:24:02.319,2)
(l,2013-02-08 00:25:30.971,0)

//Expected output(I'm returning only the id value):

1
1
2
2

//Real output:

1
1
0
2
2
0
```

This test shows that the pattern is not being applied by key, and is instead seeing all the events as belonging to the same group, which is the behaviour of a non-keyed DataStream.

If I set the quantifier to `times(2)`, that's what I get from the same input:

```
//Expected output:

1
2

//Real output:

0
0
```

I'm also receiving strange prints from my `EventoTesteConditionFunction`. It seems like some events are being checked more than once and others are being skipped.

```
//println from accepted events ofEventoTesteConditionFunction for times(2) quantifier

Event: (b,1)
Event: (c,1)
Event: (d,1)
Event: (e,1)
Event: (f,0)
Event: (h,2)
Event: (i,2)
Event: (j,2)
Event: (k,2)
Event: (l,0)
Event: (l,0)
```

Given all this, my questions are:

- How can I apply the pattern by keys?
- Why is Flink presenting such a strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you are using:

```
Pattern.begin[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]("teste").where(new EventoTesteConditionFunction(2)).times(1)
```

Says that you want to emit every record that matches your EventoTesteConditionFunction. For your use case you should rather use a pattern:

```
Pattern.begin[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]("teste").where(new AlwaysTrue()).times(2)
```

where `AlwaysTrue` returns true for all records.

The reason why you are seeing weird behaviour is because how you use the variable `c` in `EventoTesteConditionFunction`. This variable is not scoped to the key. Flink will use a single instance of `EventoTesteConditionFunction` for a single Task, which handles a subgroup of keys rather than a single key. Nevertheless results of the computation are scoped to the key. Internal state determined by the result of the function is also scoped to the key.

On a different note. For such a use case I would rather recommend looking into [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#process-function-low-level-operations). In the documentation you can also see a similar example what you are trying to do that, but using a Flink's state, that will be checkpointed and also scoped to a key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Dawid. When you say that  "Flink will use a single instance of `EventoTesteConditionFunction` for a single Task, which handles a subgroup of keys rather than a single key", you mean to say that a Task may handle multiple keys, like {a,b,c} for example, and that I can't make this Task process only id = {a}? So, I can't really have an operation applied per each unique key, right?

Comment: My initial approach was to create a `IterativeFunction` that has a `HashMap` which was gonna be used to manage the emission of each pattern detection. But I didn't know if it was the best approach, and to create a certain pattern needed in my project, a per key processing would really help me.

Comment: You can have an operation applied only to {a} key. But you cannot have a field in an operation that will be scoped to a single key. As I said in the answer if you want to have a state (any field in an operator is state) scoped to a key you must use Flink's state rather than plain fields.

Comment: Hmm, I think I got it. So, if i used a `RichFlatMapFunction`, as It's shown in [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#keyed-state), and created a private variable(say, a MapState) in it as in the example code, would It be safe to consider that this variable will only be acessed when the function is executing elements with the same key? It would be possible to make a wordcount example this way, by using the word as key, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would